# creating tables from different models with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have different models e.g. model1.py, model2.py etc. Some how tables are being created following [pocoo link](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/sqlalchemy/), which required to be invoked from terminal.

But

```
    def init_db():
        import model.model1
        import model.model2
        Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

This is not working, rather requires to be invoked from terminal.

```
>> from database import init_db
>> init_db() #works
```

[image]

---

## database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import scoped_session, sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('sqlite:///xyz.sqlite', echo=True)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False,
                                    autoflush=False,
                                    bind=engine))
Base = declarative_base()
Base.query = db_session.query_property()

def init_db():
   import model.admin # from model.admin import User doesnt help either
   import model.role
   Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

if __name__ == '__main__':
   init_db()
```

## admin.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from database import Base

class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = Column(String(50), unique=True)
    email = Column(String(120), unique=True)

    def __init__(self, name=None, email=None):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<User %r>' % (self.name)
```

There are no errors although an empty db file is generated.
How can database be created from multiple models?

Comment: What does your model.py file look like?

Comment: I got the same problem, can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why invoking directly from command line triggers table creation for you but I've always structured my Flask apps ala [Digital Ocean's guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-large-flask-applications). Something that wasn't noted explicitly in the quide is the fact that you need to initialize your blueprints first before `create_all` is able to build the database tables for you.

(Your code as it is, lacks blueprints. Maybe try to create some first then try again?)

Answer (score -1):

Use this code. `Base.metadata.create_all(engine)` It will create tables.